# Best way to transfer changes in a worksheet to corresponding sample solution with git

Tags: git

I have a worksheet with questions and exercises for my students. I also want to provide them a sample solution that expands the worksheet by the solution. I use a .tex file. So my worksheet has for example a question and my sample solution has the same question and under it the sample solution.

**worksheet.txt**

```
Question 1:
x + 2 = 7
```

**sample_solution.txt** (in branch solution)

```
Question 1:
x + 2 = 7

Solution 1:
x = 5
```

If I change some parts of the question in the worksheet (e.g. typos or modifications) I want these changes also in my sample solution.

To do that I created a new branch named solution where I expanded the worksheet by the solution. If I now make some changes on the worksheet and merge these to the solution branch, I get many merge conflicts.

Is there a better way to handle this workflow? How do you do it?

Comment: I think there's some vital context missing here. What kind of "worksheet" are you talking about, and what kind of "solution"? The sentence "a sample solution that expands the worksheet by the solution" means absolutely nothing to me, but maybe it would if I knew what technology you were working with?

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it is now more understandable.

Comment: OK, so basically you have two versions of a TeX file, and you're trying to merge them, and getting conflicts? Without knowing what's caused the conflicts (i.e. what edits you've made in the two branches that are conflicting) it's hard to make any suggestions about resolving or avoiding them. Even with an example, the advice is likely to be either "don't make those kinds of edits", or "yes, that conflict needs a human to resolve".

Comment: Not a Git use case at all.

Comment: Ok, I would also use another solution. I have two files where one is a subset of the other. If I make changes to the smaller file I want these changes to be reflected on the other file as well. Do you have any suggestions on how to do it effectively? Either I have to resolve a merge conflict or I have to apply the same change on both files separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this.  As [matt said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68133383/best-way-to-transfer-changes-in-a-worksheet-to-corresponding-sample-solution-wit#comment120421730_68133383), this is not something Git is good at or designed for.

TeX, however, can easily format the questions and answers separately even if you store them adjacent in your `.tex` file.  Define a macro or pair of macros, e.g., `\qa` or `\question` and `\answer`.  Have this number the question and, if printing the instructor's version, output *both* the question *and* the answer; if printing the student's version, omit the answer, or defer it to a separate answers chapter or booklet, etc.

To see how to define `\qa` or `\question`, etc., consider searching [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).